# Dynamodb.ScanInput - Cannot use 'expr.Names()' (type map[string]*string) as the type map[string]string

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-go

I need to scan my table in dynamodb using filtering. I found many examples in internet but when I try use them I have the same error all the time.

```
filter := expression.Name("CreatedDate").LessThan(expression.Value(time.Now().UTC()))
expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(filter).Build()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
out, err := svc.Scan(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName:                 aws.String(tableName),
    FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

On expr.Names() and expr.Values() I got error

`Cannot use 'expr.Names()' (type map[string]*string) as the type map[string]string`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify if it was a compilation error or it is shown in the panic.

Anway, the `expr.Names()` `expr.Values()` would be `map[string]*string` in case of usage `expression` from `aws-sdk-go` except `aws-sdk-go-v2`.

### Fix

Update your imports from

```
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/expression"
```

to something like below

```
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
```

Comment: Thanks. They moved expression from service to feature... That's why I didn't see that and used v1.